# ngIf doesn't display the element even though it is there

Tags: angular

```
  {{ element.number }}
  <div *ngIf="element.number">
    123
  </div>
```

It does not display 123, although the above shows the number coming from the server.

tried:

```
*ngIf="element?.number"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's hard to answer without more details.. 
Is the number 0?

Comment: Important is too: if the component/app a standalone component you need to import "CommonModule". Then a "0" or 0 is "false" in JS. so try: `*ngIf="element.number > 0"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common causes are:

- `element?.number` is undefined;
- `element?.number` is 0;
- You are not importing the `CommonModule`/`NgIF` from `@angular/core` into your `@NgModule`/Standalone feature.

If you want to show something that might be 0, then a common approach is:

```html
  {{ element.number }}
  <div *ngIf="element?.number != null">
    123
  </div>
```

This should always show the value of `element?.number` as long as it is different from `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: If it equel 0, can i still show it?

Comment: `*ngIf="element?.number !== null && element?.number !== undefined"`, see the `!==` is "strict", or `*ngIf="element?.number || element.number===0"`, see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: `*ngIf="element?.number != null` purposely relies on the week type coercion that ts/js rely on. `!=` considers null and undefined to be equal, but 0 to be false.

Comment: True, IdK4real, apologies for the confusion